# How to choose a file and download it in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, download

I'm trying to let user choose a xls file and generate a new xls file based on it for the user to download. My question is, should I use two actionresults in my Controller? One gets the file path and the other generates the new file and send it back to my View. Or I can just use one actionresult instead?

Answer (score 0):

That is entirely up to you. If you intend to store the original file somewhere, then process it later and return the derivative file, then it would make sense to use two action methods, one to upload and one to process/download. On the other hand, if it's a fairly small and quickly processed file, it might make sense to upload the file, process it, and return the derivative file all in one action method. Either way will work.

Comment: I see, then I'll probably just go for the one action method. Really thank u for your help! :)